# Hide input boxes based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a drop down menu at the top of the page to determine how many boxes are then showing on the page.

If the user selects 1, only 1 table shows
If the user selects 2, 2 tables show

I have added the code so hopefully it makes more sense

```
<body>
    <p>Please select number of puppies:</p>
    <p>
        <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<%=MM_editAction%>">
        <p>Puppy 1:  </p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <table width="330" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="PuppyName1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colour: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="PuppyColour1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sex:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="PuppySex1" id="PuppySex1">
                        <option value=" "> </option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Microchip/DNA Profile:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="PuppyMicrochip1" id="PuppyMicrochip1">
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                        <option value="Microchip">Microchip</option>
                        <option value="DNA Profile">DNA Profile</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Microchip/DNA Number:</p></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p>Puppy 2:</p>
        <table width="330" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="PuppyName2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colour: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="PuppyColour2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sex:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="PuppySex2" id="PuppySex2">
                        <option value=" "> </option>
                        <option value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Microchip/DNA Profile:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="PuppyMicrochip2" id="select2">
                        <option value="No">No</option>
                        <option value="Microchip">Microchip</option>
                        <option value="DNA Profile">DNA Profile</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p>Microchip/DNA Number:</p></td>
                <td>
                    <input name="PuppyMicrochipNum2" type="text" 
                        id="PuppyMicrochipNum2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: Have you tried any methods yet? There are a few ways to do this...

Comment: You've only added the table code. Nowhere I see a jQuery/JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes I have tried a few things that I have googled but they haven't been what i was looking for so I have removed them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h3XLP/

very common to get jQuery answers but it's really not that comprehensive with standalone JavaScript

note: add the attribute `style="display:none;"` to the second table

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
select.onchange=function(){
    if(select.value=="2"){
       document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].style.display="inline";
    }else{
       document.getElementsByTagName("table")[1].style.display="none";
    }

}
```

however you should alternatively use below, as you may have more select and table elements in your document

### http://jsfiddle.net/h3XLP/1/

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectnopuppies");
select.onchange=function(){
    if(select.value=="2"){
       document.getElementById("secondpuppytable").style.display="inline";
    }else{
       document.getElementById("secondpuppytable").style.display="none";
    }

}
```

---

```
<p>Please select number of puppies:</p>
<p>
    <select id="selectnopuppies">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</p>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<%=MM_editAction%>">
    <p>Puppy 1:</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table width="330" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="PuppyName1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colour:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="PuppyColour1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sex:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="PuppySex1" id="PuppySex1">
                    <option value=" "></option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Microchip/DNA Profile:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="PuppyMicrochip1" id="PuppyMicrochip1">
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                    <option value="Microchip">Microchip</option>
                    <option value="DNA Profile">DNA Profile</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Microchip/DNA Number:</p>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="secondpuppytable"  style="display:none;">
    <p>Puppy 2:</p>
    <table width="330" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="PuppyName2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Colour:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="PuppyColour2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sex:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="PuppySex2" id="PuppySex2">
                    <option value=" "></option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Microchip/DNA Profile:</td>
            <td>
                <select name="PuppyMicrochip2" id="select2">
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                    <option value="Microchip">Microchip</option>
                    <option value="DNA Profile">DNA Profile</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>Microchip/DNA Number:</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="PuppyMicrochipNum2" type="text" id="PuppyMicrochipNum2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your reply. I can't seems to get it working when I copy and paste the code. It is written in normal javascript isn't it?

Comment: yes, you must add the script before your closing head tag like this `<script type='text/javascript'> 
window.onload=function(){
var select = document.getElementById("selectnopuppies");
select.onchange=function(){
    if(select.value=="2"){
       document.getElementById("secondpuppytable").style.display="inline";
    }else{
       document.getElementById("secondpuppytable").style.display="none";
    }

}
}

</script>`

Comment: Brilliant that worked, not sure what I was doing wrong, thank you.

If I want to add more tables is that easy to do?

Many thanks again

Comment: Can I add more tables, 3,4,5 etc??

Comment: let me alter the code to enable you to do this, hold up one minute

Comment: 5 minutes please, what you have asked for is a bit more complex but ill have it done

Comment: when you want to add another table the id add 1 to the id and add another option to the select if your understand?

Comment: Does it need a window.onload=function() again

Comment: I can't get it too work, probably doing something wrong with the javascript in the head again

Comment: yh it does :), sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: Tried that didn't seem to work

<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload=function(){ var select = document.getElementById("selectnopuppies");
select.onchange=function(){
    var options = select.children.length+1;
    var value = parseInt(select.value);
    for(i=1;i<options;i++){
        if(i<=value){
            document.getElementById("puppytable-"+i).style.display="inline";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("puppytable-"+i).style.display="none";
        }
        
    }   }
  </script>

Comment: you have to change the html to the one in the link

Comment: `<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
var select = document.getElementById("selectnopuppies");
select.onchange=function(){
    var options = select.children.length+1;
    var value = parseInt(select.value);
    for(i=1;i<options;i++){
        if(i<=value){
            document.getElementById("puppytable-"+i).style.display="inline";
        }else{
            document.getElementById("puppytable-"+i).style.display="none";
        }
        
    }   
}
}//]]>  

</script>`

Comment: That didn't work either, thank you so much for your patience. I am sure we will get there. I've copied the html into body and the above Java into head

Comment: Thank you sooooo much. I really do appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

When you select 1st option, it will show you firSt table and for 2nd it will show you both tables.

```
$("table").hide();
$("select option").change(function(){
    Val = $(this).val();
     If(Val ==1) {
        $("table")[0].show();
        $("table")[1].hide();
      } else {
        $("table").show();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that option 1 should show table 1, option 2 show table 1 and 2, and so on.

Try this:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function(){

    var dropdown = $(this);

    var tables = $('.tableSelector');

    tables.hide();

    tables.slice(0,dropdown.val()).show();
});
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5TTz/

I have tagged all tables with a css class "tableSelector", then everytime the dropdown changes value, I show the number of tables corresponding to the current value of the dropdownlist. This solution requires the tables to be positioned in the correct order in the DOM.

However, in my ears, this sounds like a case for templates, like jQuery templates or Hoganjs.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code... It's working now... try this...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function go()
{
var Count = document.getElementById("selCount").options[document.getElementById("selCount").selectedIndex].value;
if(Count==1)
{
document.getElementById("Puppy1").style.display = '';
document.getElementById("Puppy2").style.display = 'none';
}
if(Count==2)
{
    document.getElementById("Puppy1").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("Puppy2").style.display = '';
}
}
</script>
</head>

 <body>
 <p>Please select number of puppies:</p>
 <p>
 <select onchange = "go()" id="selCount">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 </select>
 </p>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="<%=MM_editAction%>">
 <p>Puppy 1:  </p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <table width="330" border="0" id="Puppy1">
 <tr>
<td>Name: </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="PuppyName1" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Colour: </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="PuppyColour1" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Sex:</td>
 <td><select name="PuppySex1" id="PuppySex1">
 <option value=" "> </option>
 <option value="Male">Male</option>
 <option value="Female">Female</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Microchip/DNA Profile:</td>
 <td><select name="PuppyMicrochip1" id="PuppyMicrochip1">
 <option value="No">No</option>
 <option value="Microchip">Microchip</option>
 <option value="DNA Profile">DNA Profile</option>
 </select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>Microchip/DNA Number:</p></td>
 <td>&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 <p>Puppy 2:</p>
 <table width="330" border="0"  id="Puppy2">
 <tr>
 <td>Name: </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="PuppyName2" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Colour: </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="PuppyColour2" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Sex:</td>
 <td><select name="PuppySex2" id="PuppySex2">
 <option value=" "> </option>
 <option value="Male">Male</option>
 <option value="Female">Female</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Microchip/DNA Profile:</td>
 <td><select name="PuppyMicrochip2" id="select2">
 <option value="No">No</option>
 <option value="Microchip">Microchip</option>
 <option value="DNA Profile">DNA Profile</option>
 </select></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><p>Microchip/DNA Number:</p></td>
 <td><input name="PuppyMicrochipNum2" type="text" id="PuppyMicrochipNum2" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you refresh the page with this code, it has 2 tables automatically showing, I could do with just 1 showing at first and if the user selects 2 it then shows the second table

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of javascript:

```
<script>
function showtable(o){
   if(o.value==2){document.getElementById('table2').style.display='block';}
   else{document.getElementById('table2').style.display='none';}
   }
</script>

<p>Please select number of puppies:</p>
<p>
<select onchange="showtable(this)">
   <option selected value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<table id='table2' width="330" border="0" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Changes**

```
<select onchange="showForm(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);">
```

Why it's needed ?

For listening the select box value change .

```
<table width="330" border="0" class="puppy">
```

Added `class=puppy` attribute for readability . For hiding `table` element will be generic and error prone.

**Javascript Changes**

function showForm(option){
     //option user has selected.
      var val = parseInt(option.value);
      //form elements in a document.
      var forms = document.getElementsByClassName("puppy");

```
  for(var i=0,total=forms.length;i<total;i++){
     var form = forms[i];
     var display = form.style.display;
     if(i<val && display == "none"){
        form.style.display = "block";
     }else if(i >= val && display != "none"){
        form.style.display = "none";
     }
   }
```

}

Live Demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/A3eFz/31/

Answer (score 0):

Please try with following example, hope this helps.

```
<label for ="amount">Please select number of parameter</label><br/>
<select name="amount" id="amount" title="amount">
 <option value="00">0</option>
 <option value="01">1</option>
 <option value="02">2</option>
 <option value="03">3</option>
 <option value="04">4</option>
 <option value="05">5</option>
 <option value="06">6</option>
 <option value="07">7</option>
 <option value="08">8</option>
 <option value="09">9</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
<form name = "AddQuery" id = "AddQuery" method = "POST" action = "submit.php">
<div id="groups">
</div>
<div id="other">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#amount').change(function(){
 $('#groups').empty();
 var group = '';
 var number = parseInt($(this).val());
   for(var i=0;i<number;i++){
       group += '<div id="group">' +
'<label for="name['+i+']">Name'+i+'</label> '+
'<input name="name'+i+'" type="text" id="name'+i+'" value="">' +
'<label for="type['+i+']">Type'+i+'</label> '+
'<input name="type'+i+'" type="text" id="type'+i+'" value="">' +
'</div>';
}
  $('#groups').append(group);

  $('#other').empty();
  var other = '';
  other +='<div id="other"><input type="hidden" name="n" id ="n" value="'+number+'"/></div>';

$('#other').append(other);
});
});
</script>
```